# How to reduce time spent by 'readline()' from serial data

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, serial-port

I am trying to make a function to get the gyroscope components X,Y,Z from a sensor.

The function is the following:

```
def bimu_get_gyroscope_raw():
    #ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 115200, timeout=15)
    ser = serial.Serial('/dev/tty.usbserial-00002014', 115200, timeout=15)
    ser_io = io.TextIOWrapper(io.BufferedRWPair(ser, ser, 1),  
                               newline = '\r',
                               line_buffering = True)
    try:
        ser.isOpen()
        print('serial is open')
    except:
        print('error_1')
        exit()
    #--------------------
    i = 0
    gyro_dict = dict()
    if (ser.isOpen()):
        ser.flushInput()
        # write the function to get 
        while (i==0):
            try:
                print('serial is open_1')
                line = ser_io.readline()
                print('serial is open_2')
                print(line)
            except serial.SerialException as err:
                print("Error ocurred while reading data: {}".format(err))
            if not line.endswith('\r'):
                print("Attempt to read from serial port timed out ... Exiting.")
                break  # terminate the loop and let the program exit
            if line.startswith('S,'):
                i += 1
                line = line.split(',')
                print(line)
                if len(line)==12: 
                    gyro_dict = {'x':float(line[1]), 'y': float(line[2]), 'z': float(line[3]) }
    else:
        print('Cannot open serial port')
    return gyro_dict
```

I get the following output:

```
raw = bimu_get_gyroscope_raw()
print(raw)

serial is open
serial is open_1
-43,-122,-2833,83,65
serial is open_2
serial is open_1
S,2,0,0,-20,19,1014,-146,184,-158,168,99
serial is open_2
['S', '2', '0', '0', '-20', '19', '1014', '-146', '184', '-158', '168', '99\r']
{'z': 0.0, 'y': 0.0, 'x': 2.0}
```

The problem I have is that between the first time I call the line `line = ser_io.readline()` it takes about 2.25s with a hand chronometer to write on the screen `serial is open_2`.
If the function needs to call again `ser_io.readline()` there is no delay and the lines 
`serial is open_1` and `serial is open_2` appears almost at the same time.

I think the first call to `readline()` does something internally with the port or with the data buffer that once is already done makes that the successive callings to `readline()` to run much faster.

Is there any way to solve this problem and make a function run fast at all times.

**EDIT**

I have tested times with `time` python module and modified the readline part,  like this:

```
     while (i<=5):
        try:
            print('before readline')
            start_time = time.time()
            line = ser_io.readline()
            #print(line)
            print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
            #print(line)
            print('after readline')
        except serial.SerialException as err:
            print("Error ocurred while reading data: {}".format(err))
        if not line.endswith('\r'):
            print("Attempt to read from serial port timed out ... Exiting.")
            break  # terminate the loop and let the program exit
        if line.startswith('S,'):
            i += 1
            line = line.split(',')
            print(line)
            if len(line)==12: 
                gyro_dict = {'x':float(line[1]), 'y': float(line[2]), 'z': float(line[3]) }
```

with the following result:

```
    serial is open
before readline
--- 2.1859400272369385 seconds ---
after readline
before readline
--- 5.9604644775390625e-06 seconds ---
after readline
['S', '0', '0', '0', '380', '0', '-902', '-497', '-228', '200', '63', '103\r']
before readline
--- 2.86102294921875e-06 seconds ---
after readline
before readline
--- 3.814697265625e-06 seconds ---
after readline
['S', '-1', '0', '1', '375', '-8', '-918', '-497', '-223', '194', '64', '108\r']
before readline
--- 3.0994415283203125e-06 seconds ---
after readline
['S', '1', '0', '2', '380', '-10', '-909', '-500', '-223', '200', '65', '113\r']
before readline
--- 2.1457672119140625e-06 seconds ---
after readline
before readline
--- 1.9073486328125e-06 seconds ---
after readline
['S', '0', '0', '0', '379', '-1', '-914', '-500', '-220', '197', '66', '69\r']
before readline
--- 2.1457672119140625e-06 seconds ---
after readline
['S', '0', '0', '-1', '374', '-5', '-902', '-500', '-225', '1\r']
before readline
--- 3.0994415283203125e-06 seconds ---
after readline
['S', '1', '1', '1', '376', '-2', '-915', '-500', '-223', '192', '37', '75\r']
```

The function takes more than two seconds the first iteration, the rest iterations are very fast.

Comment: Readline() seems to be an I/O operation. How about using threading to increase performance by reducing I/O latency. The idea is to create two threads: 1) dedicated to just reading data from the serial port and 2) the main thread dedicated to just processing the data.

Comment: @nathancy Thank you. The problem I have is that the first output line `-43,-122--2833, 83,65`, which is the primary data that the function reads takes about 3s, whereas the rest of the lines are speedy. I do not know if we separate reading from processing will speed up the output of the function. The function should run fast from the beginning. I do not understand what can occur in the first readline() to be so slow.

Comment: @nathancy the serial port is already opened when the function makes the first readline. When I run the function it writes immediately `serial is open` and serial is open_1` just before the readline, then it takes 3s to write the first data numbers and after that is very fast (instantaneously).

Comment: What is the frequency of sensor data? Given that you use `readline` and `split`, I assume you use ASCII data. Is there a way to configure the sensor to output binary data?

Comment: @Kani Thank you. The sample rate I use is 64Hz. I have to look if it is possible to configure the sensor to get binary.

Comment: Have you checked that a simple `cat -u /dev/tty.usbserial-00002014` doesn't have the same 2 second delay before data starts to appear?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a couple of suggestions for you.  I write Windows applications that use a serial port and I use a different approach - I assume the principles would be the same across all OS's.  I create and open the port first, at the beginning of the program, and leave it open.  It's good practice to close the port before your program exists but that's not really necessary, since the OS will clean up afterwards.

But your code will create and initialize the port each time you call the function.  You're not explicitly closing it when you're done; perhaps you can get away with that because the port object gets garbage collected.  You are trusting the serial library to close the port properly at the OS level before you try to open it again.  In any case, if there is overhead in creating the port object, why not incur it once and be done with it?

You don't need to create a TextIOWrapper at all, let alone a bi-directional one.  You're wondering if it's the reason for your performance issues, so why not get rid of it?  The serial port library has all the functionality you need: check out the `read_until` function.

I think you ought to start with a framework something like this.  I can't run and test this program, so it's a schematic only.  I have stripped out all the error handling code.  One small issue is that serial ports operate on bytes and you have to convert that to a string.

```
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/tty.usbserial-00002014', 115200, timeout=15)
def bimu_get_gyroscope_raw():
    while True:
        ser.flushInput()
        b = ser.read_until('\r')
        s = str(b, encoding='latin1')  # convert to str
        if a.startswith('S,'):
            line = s.split(',')
            if len(line)==12: 
                return dict(x = float(line[1]),
                            y = float(line[2]),
                            z = float(line[3]))
```

I have made `ser` a global but you could also pass it to the function as an argument.

Keep in mind how serial ports work on a modern OS.  You are never reading the characters directly from the hardware - the OS is doing that for you, and placing the characters in an input buffer.  When you "read" from the port you are actually retrieving any characters from the buffer, or waiting for their arrival.  What you observe - a long delay followed by a rapid succession of lines of data - could be explained by the gyroscope hardware doing nothing for several seconds, and then producing a burst of data that's more than one line long.  I don't know how your gyroscope works so I can't say that this is really the case.

The PySerial implementation is actually a wrapper around a set of operating system calls.  The Python overhead is very minimal, and much of it is error-handling code.  I am sure you will be able to receive thousands of characters per second using Python - I do it all the time.  Three seconds is close to eternity on a modern PC.  There must be another explanation for it.  Don't think for a moment that Python is your bottleneck.

Timing events by looking at the screen and clicking a stopwatch is clumsy.  Look at the Python time package.  You could simply print the value of time.time() in each of your print statements and put away your chronometer.

You can test the data gathering part of the implementation independently.  Just strip out the logic to parse the data, and stay in the while loop forever.  Print the data along with time stamps for each received line.  If you have another instrument that talks to a serial port you can isolate the performance of the instrument from the performance of the software.

Finally, what event causes the gyroscope to make a data transmission?  Is it one of those instruments that just periodically broadcasts its data, or do you have to send it some command to request the data?  If the former and the broadcasts are every three seconds, the mystery is solved; likewise if it's the latter and the latency in the response is three seconds.  I can imagine that some such thing might be the case, since the instrument will have to read some sensors and translate the results to a character string.  You haven't shown us the whole program or told us how the instruments works, so this is just guesswork.

Comment: @PaulCornellius The gyroscope sample rate is 64Hz. I believe this is not causing the delay. If I ask for five gyroscope x,y,z data, the delay is produced only with the first x,y,z. The rest outputs very fast.

Comment: @PaulCornellius The sensor is specially indicated to capture motion and orientation. Here is a link of the sensor https://x-io.co.uk/x-bimu/ , which is xBee wireless instrument.

Comment: @PaulCornellius I am going to edit the question to add the timing of readline().

Comment: @PaulCornellius When I run `ser.flushInput(); b = ser.read_until('\r')` lines then the variable `b` has a lot of data, like this: print(b)
b'502,-225,200,151,118\rQ,-182,9735,-1013,1957,203,90\rS,2,0,0,373,-3,-904,-505,-225,194,152,123\rS,0,0,0,378,-8,-913,-502,-225,197,153,122\rQ,-182,9735,-1012,1957,204,92\rS,1,-1,0,375,-7,-904,-505,-225,194,154,80\rS,0,-1,0,374,-3,-909,-505,-225,194,155,88\rQ,-182,9735,-1012,1957,205,93\rS,0,0,0,380,-3,-902,-505,-225,197,156,116\rS,1,0,0,380,-4,-909....the stop condition should be different because I receive `\r` with the letter of the next line.

Comment: @user1993416 I think you need to use `read_until(b'\r')` as the input at this point is in bytes, not a string.

Comment: From the web page you linked: "A low-latency motion triggered wake up feature allows the x-BIMU to extend battery life by entering a low power state during periods of inactivity. The device can wake up when activity is detected and begin streaming with no loss of motion measurement data." Have you checked this out?  Please answer my question about whether they gyroscope streams the data asynchronously or in response to a command.

Comment: After the 3s lag occurs once and the device begins streaming, does the stream continue thereafter with no further delays?  If that's the case, just get it started at the beginning of the application and it will be fast from then on - problem solved.  But if you have to send a command to retrieve the data, and the command is always followed by a 3s delay, then you have a different problem.  That's why I  keep asking this question.

Comment: @PaulCornellius It is working fine. Just I had to update Serial module and use the comment of `meuh`. The trick is to open the port before calling the function for data. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Notice a few things you should observe.

First of all, when you start your application, you should instance all the resources and leave it there for use.
The serial port has an input buffer, and so, you can access data in an assynchronous way, you don't need to stay listening for the client, but, if the port is closed, all data received before it's been opened will be discarded and not added to the buffer. That's why you must leave the port ALWAYS open.

What I usually do in my applications is to abstract the serial port and create an object to deal with the device.
This object will open the port and have a Rx thread (no need for a Tx thread since python runs in a synchronous way thanks to the GIL) and keep watching for new data.
To send a data you should just call the '__send_command'.
To get the received data, take it from the Rx queue of the object.

This is a code I use frequently to communicate with Serial devices (I work with industrial automation where Serial is a common interface). It's been fulfilling my needs. I made some changes to remove the device specific helper functions from my device (an industrial scale), but left one as . Just add yours!

**Don't forget to check how often your module sends the data, usually this time basis can be configured on a specific register of the module. Usually goes from few milliseconds to many seconds interval.**

```
import serial    # pip install pyserial
import io
import time
import threading


class SerialDevice():

    def __init__(self, baudrate=9600, port='COM1', timeout=0.1):
        self.ser = serial.Serial()
        self.ser.baudrate = baudrate
        self.ser.port = port
        self.ser.timeout = timeout
        self.sio = io.TextIOWrapper(io.BufferedRWPair(self.ser, self.ser), newline='\r\n')
        self.received_data = []


    def connect(self):
        try:
            self.ser.open()
            time.sleep(0.1)
            self.clear_data()
            self.__control_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.__receive_handler, args=())
            self.__control_thread.start()
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            return False
        return self.ser.is_open


    def disconnect(self):
        try:
            if(self.ser.is_open):
                self.ser.close()
                return True
            else:
                return False
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            return False


    def connected(self):
        return self.ser.is_open


    def data_available(self):
        return len(self.received_data)


    def get_data(self):
        '''Pop the first item from the received data list'''
        if(len(self.received_data)):
            return self.received_data.pop(0)
        return None


    def peek_data(self):
        '''Pop the first item from the received data list'''
        if(len(self.received_data)):
            return self.received_data[0]
        return None


    def clear_data(self):
        '''Clear the received data list'''
        self.received_data.clear()


    def __receive_handler(self):
        while(not self.ser.is_open): # Waits for the port to open
            time.sleep(0.1)
        # Clear serial input buffer
        self.ser.read(self.ser.in_waiting)
        while(self.ser.is_open):
            try:
                if(self.ser.in_waiting):
                    data = self.ser.readline()
                    self.received_data.append(self.__unpack_data(data))
                    print('received! {}'.format(data))
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
            time.sleep(0.001)


    def __unpack_data(self, data=''):
        '''Unpacks the received data to the measurement format
        Receives the binary array and returns a Measurement object'''
        # Decode the received data here and return it processed as an object to the received_data queue
        # in this case I'll just return the same daata
        return data



    def __send_command(self, command):
        # send the command using serial port
        # Return 1 if success, 0 if error
        try:
            if(self.ser.is_open):
                self.ser.write((command + '\r\n').encode('ascii'))
                return 1
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
        return 0


# this is a helper function to send commands to your device
    def send_global_reset(self):
        '''Global reset to reset all menu settings to the original factory defaults'''
        return self.__send_command('Esc R')
```

Comment: Thank you. I have change the baudrate and the port in your code. I am trying to use it. Could you tell me how to get a line starting with 'S' character. What should I run?. Foer example, if I run `SerialDevice.get_data()` tells me `TypeError: get_data() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'`.

Comment: When I call for the data, I would like to get the current values of the gyroscope, not the buffered one. Does your code do that way?

Comment: You can use something like this:
data = 'ABCSDFG'
index=data.find('S') or index=data.index('S') to check if the character exists in the string, if it does, you'll get it's position..  then split the string as you wish using the split operator
my_string=data[index:]  in this case you'll get the string from the 'S' to it's end, so in this example should get my_string=='SDFG'

Comment: As the gyro sends the data it's buffered into the application received data queue by the receiveing thread, so it garantees the reception in realtime. So you could add a timestamp to the object when you add it to the data_received queue.

Another approach would be to check if you gyro can work on a Request/Response basis, this way you'll always have an updated value as you'll receive it only when it's been asked.

There are many approaches, but it depends on the hardware resources you are interfacing. You need to check wich approach fits best for you. I prefer method 1 using the timestamp.

Comment: I apologize, but after reading your comments, I still do not know how I could get the gyrospcope xyz data of the sensor motion at the moment run the function. Besides, I do not know what to execute in python to get the data. May I ask you to adapt your code or detail on how to get the data I am looking.

Comment: What is the model of the gyro you're trying to interface with? Do you have it's datasheet? Send the link so we can check on the protocol details to help you parse the data.

Comment: It is an IMU. The instrument web is in https://x-io.co.uk/x-bimu/ . The device has gyro, accelerometer, and magnetometer. The data comes in lines (ended with \r). Each line start with a letter. The letter `S` has the XYZ of the gyro. There are lines that start with `B` of battery data, `Q` of quaternion angles. Battery data comes much less frequently than S and Q lines. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score -2):

I think you using a implementation in c might help. The python codes internally call a c function to perform its task. If you use the underlying functions directly it would save time.
I haven't tried it anytime. but this might help.

https://github.com/EveryTimeIWill18/Cython_Repo/blob/master/FastFileProcessingWithCython.ipynb

Comment: No need to go that deep. If you need something fast, could just add a callback to the receive thread.